# Predicate re-write in where clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql

How can I rewrite `where col % 5 = 4` in SQL Server. The reason to rewrite this is because I am selecting some columns from the table based on this condition. Because of % used in where it is causing index scan instead of seek. Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way would be to add a computed column to the table with your mod calculation, and then create an index or add it to an existing index.

For example:

```
-- Test table and values
CREATE TABLE #Test (col integer PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT #Test (col)
VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5);

-- Original query (scan)
SELECT T.col 
FROM #Test AS T
WHERE col % 5 = 4;

-- Add computed column (no need for persisted)
ALTER TABLE #Test
ADD col_mod5 AS col % 5;

-- Index computed column
CREATE INDEX i
ON #Test (col_mod5)
INCLUDE (col);

-- Index seek
SELECT T.col 
FROM #Test AS T
WHERE col % 5 = 4;

-- Tidy up
DROP TABLE #Test;
```

[image: Plan]

Another alternative is to create an indexed view selecting what you need from the table, plus a column with the mod calculation, and refer to that in your queries. You do this by declaring the view as schemabinding and then creating a clustered index on it as if it were a table.

If you are using Enterprise Edition, you *may* not need to change your query to use the view. Otherwise, you will need to reference the view explicitly and use the `NOEXPAND` hint. The indexed computed column is the lighter weight solution.